# Laravel migrate on production server

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I'm using Laravel and as part of my deploy routine I have the command

`RUN php artisan migrate`

Since I'm in production, I get the error

> Application in production, Command Cancelled!

The fix is easy: `RUN php rankbot/artisan migrate --force` but I feel this is not the right way to do it? What's the best way to ensure the DB schema is always up to date?

Comment: `--force`  is the right way to do it. The `--force` flag prevent you from accidentally running your migrations on a production environment. Like when you have 2 ssh terminals open or something.

Comment: If migration takes a long time with --force and internet connection is lost while connected to server...what happens? Can nohup be used? (nohup php artisan migrate --force)

Answer (score 43):

This is the right way to go about it.

When you run a migration on production, you best be sure what it's going to do to your database, as some actions might not be rollbackable.

The *confirmation prompt* is there to make you stop and think twice before potentially cause harm.

> Some migration operations are destructive, which means they may cause
> you to lose data. In order to protect you from running these commands
> against your production database, you will be prompted for
> confirmation before the commands are executed. To force the commands
> to run without a prompt, use the --force flag
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#running-migrations

Comment: Each case must be taken into account. If you have 100 servers to update, manual confirmations are not helpful. So `--force` is the way to go for automated deploys